# In QUERY on unique values, NO_COLUMN error

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-query-language

I have a list of U.S. states where duplicate values are also available. I need to find how many unique states are there in a list.

'Unique' function returns all the unique states but in conjunction with 'query' function the following error message is returned:

> Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: A

```
=query(unique(A3:A26),"Select count(A)")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Having reconstructed the data (after UNIQUE it is different) you can't then continue with letters for column references. So:

```
=query(unique(A3:A26),"Select count(Col1)")
```